# How to get the median of a list?

Tags: python

And how do i use it using built in functions only so no imports?
This works if there is only one meian value but if there is 2 median values then it doesn't work.

```
def medianoflist(list1):
    x = int((len(list1) + 1)/2)
    print(list1[x-1])
```

so when i do something like `list1 = [(1,2,3)]` it works. But when I do something like `[(1,2,3,4)]` it outputs 2, which is the lower median value. For this case I need to avrage the upper median value and the lower median value, help please I can't figure it out. Also I cannot use any statistic imports.

Comment: Well, you have two cases: an even number of elements in the list, and an odd number of elements in the list. Do a test to see which case it falls in, and handle it appropriately by dividing your function up into those two cases. You’ve handled one already. The other one is a little different, but isn’t too much of a stretch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This covers both cases:

```
def medianoflist(l):
    x = (l[int((len(l)-1)/2)] + l[int(len(l)/2)])/2
    print x
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your "only builtin functions" requirement means no imports at all, or no third-party imports. If standard library imports are OK, then as of Python 3.4 you can use the new `statistics` module:

```
import statistics
statistics.median([1, 2, 3, 4])
Out[2]: 2.5
statistics.median_low([1, 2, 3, 4])
Out[3]: 2
```